# migrating TAAE2 to AudioKit 3

Tags: audiokit

I have a large project built with `The Amazing Audio Engine 2`. I have struggled to get Inter-App-Audio integrated and would like to migrate to AudioKit 3.

Struggled, meaning, it integrates, but as soon as I select it as a generator the rendering just stops, the engine is in a disabled state.

What are the main differences with the audio systems? TAAE2 uses modules, each with a render block, that pushes and pops audio buffers from a render stack.

How does AudioKit render audio? What would be involved, on a high level, in migrating AEModules to Audiokit objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the audio rendering, it's essentially a wrapper around AVAudioEngine, AUAudioUnit, AVAudioUnit, and AVAudioNode.  It's conceptualized as a render chain rather than a stack, but the end result is the same.  You can use the system Audio units, or you can register your own by creating an AUAudioUnit subclass.

The render chain works much the same way, but with a block based API.  Instead of subclassing AEAudioUnitModule and setting the processFunction  to a C function where you pull buffer lists and timestamps from your renderer, you subclass AUAudioUnit and implement [internalRenderBlock](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/audiotoolbox/auinternalrenderblock?language=objc) where you return a block that gets called with the buffers and timestamps as arguments to your block.  This block is where you could do most of your porting.

Comment: Thanks Dave, so it sounds similar to TAAE1. How is the order of the chain setup? E.g. polyphonic voices with multiple oscillators, being modulated by LFOs and Envelope generators, TAAE2 allows specifically calling process on a module, how is this done with AudioKit?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, the biggest difference is that instead of being able to call a process _on_ a module you must add that process as a node that the audio will pass _through_.  So if you want to process only on some of your oscillators, you would have to "route" the output of some of the oscillators through your envelope filters.  The AVAudioEngine family sort of follows a physical model (generator -> patch cable -> effect)  rather than a buffer manipulation model.

Comment: Im trying to understand how AVAudioEngine's design can support the polyphonic voices. Lets say we have 1 voice, with 1 oscillator, which has 1 LFO and 1 Envelope, In TAAE2 the main render function can call render on the voice, which then calls oscillator.render, lfo.render, envelope.render. How is this setup in AVAudioEngine with the node connections? Would it be audioEngine.connect(voice1, to: audioEngine.mainMixerNode, format: audioFormat) and then in the voice object audioEngine.connect(oscillator, to: self, format: audioFormat), audioEngine.connect(lfo, to: oscillator .. etc. ?

Comment: It would look like this (shortened functions for brevity): `engine.connect(voice, to: LFO) engine.connect(LFO, to: Envelope) engine.connect(Envelope, to engine.mainMixer)`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not exactly sure is this not right answer. but could it be the same as this discussion in our doc ?

[migrating to AudioKit](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/audiokit/PVl0vKc7EcU)

Comment: Kind of, Im interested in the architecture involved when migrating from TAAE2 render callback and stack system, to AudioKit. I would like to know how the engine's processing design works in AudioKit. How can the buffers be passed for playback and how it works with a system using multiple modules, all needed audio buffers to be processed and chained.